# What was up with Ned's Dad?

Tags: pushing-daisies

In Pushing Daisies, there is an episode which mentions that Ned's Dad saved him, then little mention is made for the rest of the series. What was his deal?

Comment: That was a really fun series.  I enjoyed the odd style.  Alas, it appears I was not accompanied by many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikia](http://pushing-daisies.wikia.com/wiki/Ned%27s_Father) (the article references all these details to specific episodes so I consider it credible), the "his deal" is that:

- He abandoned Ned after Ned's mother died ( His parting words to his son were, "I'll be back." - as per the narrator, he lied)
- He re-married, and then abandoned that family (with 2 twins) with the same parting words.
- He is still around, for some reason helping Ned (not explained why, but possibly to atone for abandoning?):

  - He  saved Ned and Olive Snook from falling to their deaths.
  - He also managed to set up Dwight Dixon's body in his hotel room in such a way to appear as if he had died of natural causes and was responsible for the missing bodies in Charles and Charlotte's graves, helping his son and his friends.

---

Leaving aside the show material, there were apparently some unspecified plans to continue the story of Ned's father before the show was canelled.

From an [interview with Fuller:](http://blastr.com/2009/05/bryan-fuller-how-pushing.php)

> The producers did have a plan, but that plan didn't include getting canceled in their second season after 13 episodes, Fuller said. "The unfortunate thing about how we were breaking the season was that we were taking a break from the Chuck and Ned central storyline for three episodes to tell an Olive story, to tell an Emerson story, to tell a Lily/Vivian story," Fuller said. "**And then with episode 14, open back up the whole thing with Chuck's father and Ned's father in a bigger way that was going to be our arc of the back nine of the season**, ... but we ended up not getting a back nine. So, in an unfortunate way, **those elements of Chuck's father and Ned's father and the pocket watches, that story is the story that's going to be continued in the comic book. So we'll understand all about that, but the three episodes that are about to air I'm really excited about."**

Notice the last bit - the story was supposed to wrap up in the comic book.

BUT... [the comic book got cancelled as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushing_Daisies#Comics).

And that's all she wrote.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing the dad brought Ned back to life when he was a child and couldn't bear to not touch him. That's my story and I'm sticking to it

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have any evidence for this theory?  Answers should be more than just fan theories, they should be based in the source material; you might want to read [answer] and take the [tour].

Comment: It's fiction you don't need evidence or even continnuity.. for example how did Ned know he couldn't touch Diggby?. According to the narrative he had no knowledge of the second fatal touch until his mom died.